# Vuetify grid height one row that grows and one fixed at the bottom

Tags: css, flexbox, vuetify.js

I'am implementing [Vuetify Flex](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/) for my [grid rows](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/) but having trouble with the classes.

There is two v-row in this container, I want the first to grow all all available height and keep the second one at the bottom but still showing.

Picture of what I want: [image]

`code`

This is my codepen so far: https://codepen.io/5less/pen/mdWpjWR

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you're trying to achieve there may be different solutions, but based on what is shown in the picture you can use `style="height: 90vh"` for the first `v-row` and `style="height: 10vh"` for the second one. check out the code below and see if it helps:

```js
// you can ignore this line
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```css
.br {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.bb {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-row class="br" style="height: 90vh"></v-row>
        <v-row class="bb" style="height: 10vh"></v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: "I want the first to grow all all available height [...]" sounds more like: the bottom row should fit to it's content and the top row should take all remaining space.

Comment: @Fred Yes you are correct, that is what i'am after. 

Also: By using vh I get different results in desktop / mobile screens.